# Inserting special ascii characters into a file using VBA (excel)

Tags: file, vba, text, escaping, ascii

I am fairly new to VBA, but not to coding in general.  I have an Excel worksheet, part of which I need to export into a text file.  However, to ensure the escape characters don't collide with anything written in the worksheet, and also to match up with how escape characters are handled in other (Java & C) apps at our company, I would like to use the ascii character "[thorn](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/lowercase-letter-thorn-ascii-code-231.html)".

Some languages that I know, like perl, will simply let you enter an escape character and the ascii number of the symbol.  E.g., I could type "\231" in order to get "[thorn](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/lowercase-letter-thorn-ascii-code-231.html)".  It seems this is not supported in VBA.  Or if it is, I am not sure how.

Lastly, below is a brief snippet of how I imagine I would implement the code, with just the key statements.  If you have a better suggestion, or know why this wouldn't be the best way, please let me know.

```
Open sFullPath For Output As #1
```

(... some code to capture the values to be written to the next line of the file ...)

```
sLine = Join(sValues, <the thorn character>)
Print #1, sLine
```

The code above would be placed within a loop that would regenerate "sValues", the set of relevant cells in the next row to be printed to the text file.

Thanks so much!

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print an ASCII character using its code number, use the `chr()` function

Extended ASCII isn't standard across all platforms. For whatever reason, the number needed is 222.

So you would need

```
sLine = Join(sValues, chr(222))
Print #1, sLine
```

Comment: I'm *fairly* sure the character number required is actually 254. Your answer hadn't appeared at the point when I hit post for mine (I loaded the page a few minutes ago). In the immediate window type: `? asc("þ")` using Alt+231 for the character.

Comment: When I use chr(222) I get the thorn character. But it appears one is uppercase and the other is lowercase. Good catch :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  I just couldn't seem to find documentation referring to "Chr()".

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `<the thorn character>` with `Chr(254)`. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: @brettdj I've been overcompensated and feel guilty! Haha. Thank you though, I do appreciate it :)